# PHP Function to count no. of yahoo backlinks

Tags: php, yahoo

I am using this code to check but not getting result. Here I am trying to get backlinks of google.com in yahoo.

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$page = file_get_contents("http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/search?p=$url&bwm=i&bwmf=a&bwms=p");    
$expression = '/<span class="btn">Inlinks \((.*)\)<i class="tl"><\/i>/Us';  
preg_match($expression, $page, $matches);   
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Yahoo stopped the service ? http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the source, there's no `<i class="tl"></i>` after `Inlinks (...)`. Which itself sums up pretty fine why regular expressions are a terrible tool for these kind of things in the first place. Nevertheless, it should work if you use the following expression:

```
$expression = '/<span class="btn">Inlinks \((.*)\)/';
```